# What are terms and functions in the first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to learn the syntax of the first order logic. On Wikipedia I see these rules:

1. Any variable is a term.
2. Any expression $f(t_1,...,t_n)$ of $n$ arguments (where each argument $t_i$ is a term and $f$ is a function symbol of valence $n$) is a term.

I understand variables as references to specific objects (for example `Berlin`, `USA`, `John`, `Marry`, `Jupiter`). I also understand functions as something that get variable as inputs and generate set of variables. For example: `ChildrenOf(John, Marry)` will returns a set of children of John and Marry and this set, according to the rule 2, is a term by itself. So, it can be used as an argument of a function. But how then the following function should be interpreted:

```
ChildrenOf(ChildrenOf(John, Marry), ChildrenOf(Bill, Anna))
```

In other words, how should I evaluate functions if we use sets as their arguments? I can assume that in the above example the function should return all the people for whom the one of the parents is offspring of John and Marry and another parent is offspring of Bill and Anna but I am not sure that this is correct since it is not stated explicitly on Wikipedia.

Comment: Where are you taking this example from? is this some introduction to set theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also understand functions as something that get variable as inputs and generate set of variables.

That's **incorrect**: semantically, a function takes in a tuple of values and outputs a **single** value. This is present in the definition of a structure, where each function symbol is interpreted as a literal single-valued function on that structure. So we don't run into the problem you're worried about at all, and composition of functions is perfectly benign.

*It's also not accurate to say that functions output variables: variables are specific types of symbols, and a string like "$f(x_1,x_2)$" is simply not a symbol of that type. But this is really a side issue.*

---

Separately, a bit of intuition which might be helpful: you should think of a term as a **noun**, possibly a vague noun in case variables are involved (until we pick a variable *assignment* such a term doesn't pick out a specific element of a given structure) but a noun nonetheless. A function symbol by contrast is *part of a noun phrase* which begins with the word "the" to reflect its single-valuedness (e.g. "the smallest prime number greater than ---").